# React State Updating issue - Comments System

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

i am building a comments system with a Firebase back end for my recipe website. I have so far managed to:

-Add a comment (appears immediately in UI)
-Delete a Comment (removes immediately in UI)
-Add a Reply (adds immediately in UI)
-Edit a comment (updates immediately in UI)

What i cant seem to do, believe me i have tried various things over 2 weeks now, is delete a reply.

**My Data structure looks like this:**

- ReplyText (string)
- Avatar (string, url to firestore storage)
- User (string)
- RecipeId (string, used to identify the recipe the comment is associated with)
- replies [array of objects] - i dont think firebase has a conventional approach to arrays which has meant i have had to get the document and do a full update instead of something like arrayRemove()

**Problem**
No matter which way i try and approach it, i cannot get replies to update correctly in state after it has been deleted.It deletes fine from the backend firestore database so a page refresh renders everything corrected. I know its something stupid but ive been in a whole so long i need help.
I am trying to update Repliess state which i hoped would do the re-render but its not happening.

**Comments.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import firebase from '../../../firebase/initFirebase'
import {
    getFirestore, collection, where, query, orderBy, limit, onSnapshot, addDoc, serverTimestamp
} from 'firebase/firestore'
import Backdrop from '@mui/material/Backdrop';
import SingleComment from "./SingleComment";
import CircularProgress from '@mui/material/CircularProgress';
import Stack from '@mui/material/Stack';
import Container from '@mui/material/Container';
import { AuthContext } from "../../../context/AuthContext";

const Comments = ({ recipeId }) => {
    const [commentsLoading, setCommentsLoading] = useState(true);
    const [comments, setComments] = useState([]);
    const db = getFirestore()
    const commentsRef = collection(db, 'comments')
    const [last, setLast] = useState(null);
    const { currentUser } = useContext(AuthContext);

    const handleCommentDeleted = (id) => {
        const updatedComments = comments.filter((comment) => comment.id !== id);
        setComments(updatedComments);

    };
    useEffect(() => {
        const q = query(collection(db, "comments"), where("recipeId", "==", recipeId), orderBy("createdAt", "desc"));
        const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
            const getCommentsFromFirebase = [];
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                getCommentsFromFirebase.push({
                    id: doc.id,
                    ...doc.data()
                })
            });
            setComments(getCommentsFromFirebase)
            setCommentsLoading(false)

        });
        return unsubscribe
    }, [recipeId]);


    if (commentsLoading) {
        return (
            <Backdrop
                sx={{ color: '#fff', zIndex: (theme) => theme.zIndex.drawer + 1 }}
                open={commentsLoading}
            >
                <CircularProgress color="inherit" />
            </Backdrop>
        )
    }

    return (

        < div >
            < Container maxWidth="md" >
                <Stack spacing={3}>
                    {comments && comments.map((comment) => {
                        return <SingleComment key={comment.id} replyId={comment.replies} onPass={comment} onCommentDeleted={handleCommentDeleted} />; //onReplyDelete={handleDeleteReply}
                    })}
                </Stack>
            </Container >
        </div >

    );
};

export default Comments;
```

**SingleComment.js**

```
import Button from '@mui/material/Button'
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography'
import Card from '@mui/material/Card'
// import ThemeProvider from '@mui/material/styles/ThemeProvider'
import Stack from '@mui/material/Stack'
import Avatar from '@mui/material/Avatar'
import Box from '@mui/material/Box'
import React, { useState, useContext } from "react";
import { Delete, Edit } from "@mui/icons-material";
import replyArrow from "../../../public/assets/icon-reply.svg"
import Image from 'next/image'
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import ConfirmDelete from './ConfirmDelete'
import { AuthContext } from '../../../context/AuthContext'
import YouTag from "./YouTag";
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField'
import {
    getFirestore, doc, updateDoc
} from 'firebase/firestore'
import RepliesSection from './RepliesSection'
// import theme from "../theme";
const SingleComment = ({ onPass, onCommentDeleted, onReplyDelete }) => {
    // console.log(replyId)
    const auth = getAuth();
    const user = auth.currentUser;
    const { id, text, createdAt, postedBy, replies, avatar } = onPass;
    const [editingComm, setEditingComm] = useState(false);
    const [commentText, setCommentText] = useState(text);
    const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false);
    const [openModal, setOpenModal] = useState(false);
    const { userData } = useContext(AuthContext);
    const [replyId, setReplyId] = useState(null)


    const displayName = user.displayName;
    const ava = user.photoURL
    // console.log(ava)
    const db = getFirestore()
    const docRef = doc(db, 'comments/' + onPass.id)

    const handleOpen = () => {
        setOpenModal(true);
    };

    const handleClose = () => {
        setOpenModal(false);

    };
    const handleUpdate = (event) => {


        updateDoc(docRef, {
            text: commentText
        })
            .then(() => {
                setEditingComm(!editingComm)

            })
    }


    return (


        <Card sx={{ mt: "1em", }}>
            <ConfirmDelete setReplyId={setReplyId} onOpen={openModal} onClose={handleClose} id={onPass.id} onCommentDeleted={onCommentDeleted} />

            <Box sx={{ p: "15px", }}>
                <Stack spacing={2} direction="row">
                    <Box>
                        {/* <ScoreChanger onScore={"1"} /> */}
                    </Box>
                    <Box sx={{ width: "100%" }}>
                        <Stack
                            spacing={2}
                            direction="row"
                            justifyContent="space-between"
                            alignItems="center"
                        >
                            <Stack spacing={2} direction="row" alignItems="center">

                                <Avatar src={avatar}></Avatar>


                                <Typography
                                    fontWeight="bold"
                                    sx={{ color: "neutral.darkBlue" }}
                                >
                                    {postedBy}

                                </Typography>
                                {user && postedBy === user.displayName && <YouTag />}
                                <Typography sx={{ color: "neutral.grayishBlue" }}>
                                    {createdAt && createdAt.toDate().toLocaleString()}
                                </Typography>
                            </Stack>
                            {user && postedBy === user.displayName ? (
                                <Stack direction="row" spacing={1}>
                                    <Button
                                        startIcon={<Delete />}
                                        sx={{
                                            color: "custom.softRed",
                                            fontWeight: 500,
                                            textTransform: "capitalize",
                                        }}
                                        onClick={() => {
                                            handleOpen();
                                        }}
                                    >
                                        Delete
                                    </Button>
                                    <Button
                                        variant="text"
                                        disabled={editingComm}
                                        sx={{
                                            fontWeight: 500,
                                            textTransform: "capitalize",
                                            color: "custom.moderateBlue",
                                        }}
                                        startIcon={<Edit />}
                                        onClick={() => setEditingComm(!editingComm)}
                                    >
                                        Edit
                                    </Button>
                                </Stack>
                            ) : (
                                <Button
                                    onClick={() => {
                                        setClicked(!clicked);
                                    }}
                                    variant="text"
                                    sx={{
                                        fontWeight: 500,
                                        textTransform: "capitalize",
                                        color: "custom.moderateBlue",
                                    }}
                                    startIcon={<Image src={replyArrow} alt="reply sign" />}
                                >
                                    Reply
                                </Button>
                            )}
                        </Stack>
                        {editingComm ? (
                            <>
                                <TextField
                                    sx={{ p: "20px 0" }}
                                    multiline
                                    fullWidth
                                    minRows={4}
                                    id="outlined-multilined"
                                    placeholder="Don't leave this blank!"
                                    value={commentText}
                                    onChange={(e) => {
                                        setCommentText(e.target.value);
                                    }}
                                />
                                <Button
                                    sx={{
                                        float: "right",
                                        bgcolor: "custom.moderateBlue",
                                        color: "neutral.white",
                                        p: "8px 25px",
                                        "&:hover": {
                                            bgcolor: "custom.lightGrayishBlue",
                                        },
                                    }}
                                    onClick={() => {
                                        !commentText.trim()
                                            ? alert(
                                                "If  you want to remove the comment text, just delete the comment."
                                            )
                                            : handleUpdate()
                                    }}
                                >
                                    Update
                                </Button>
                            </>
                        ) : (
                            <Typography sx={{ color: "neutral.grayishBlue", p: "20px 0" }}>
                                {commentText}
                            </Typography>
                        )}
                        {

                            <RepliesSection
                                onPass={onPass}
                                onReplies={replies}
                                onClicked={clicked}
                                onTar={user}
                                ava={ava}
                                displayName={displayName}
                                postedBy={postedBy}
                                comId={id}
                                onCommentDeleted={onCommentDeleted}

                                replyId={replyId}

                            />

                        }
                    </Box>
                </Stack>

            </Box >


        </Card >



    )




}
export default SingleComment
```

**RepliesSection.js**

```
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
// import ScoreChanger from "./ScoreChanger";
import replyArrow from "../../../public/assets/icon-reply.svg"
import OwnReply from "./OwnReply.js";
import { getFirestore, doc, deleteDoc, getDoc, updateDoc, } from "firebase/firestore";
const RepliesSection = ({ onReplies, onClicked, onTar, onPass, avatar, displayName, ava, postedBy, comId, onCommentDeleted, onReplyDelete, repyId }) => {

    const [repliess, setReplies] = useState(onReplies);
    // console.log(repliess)
    const db = getFirestore()
    const docRef = doc(db, 'comments/' + `${comId}`)

    const deleteReply = async (replyId) => {

        try {
            let getSingleCommentData = []
            await getDoc(docRef).then((doc) => {
                getSingleCommentData.push({ ...doc.data(), key: doc.id })
            })

            const updatedReplies = getSingleCommentData[0].replies.filter(
                (reply) => reply.replyId !== replyId
            );


            await updateDoc(docRef, {
                replies: updatedReplies

            });
            setReplies(updatedReplies);

            // onCommentDeleted(id);

        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error deleting comment:", error);
        }

    };


    return (
        <Stack spacing={2} width="800px" alignSelf="flex-end">
            {repliess && Array.isArray(repliess) && repliess.length > 0 &&

                repliess.map((rep) => {
                    const { createdAt, score, user, replyingTo, replyId, avatar, recipeId, postedBy, replyText } = rep;

                    const userName = displayName;

                    return userName === displayName ? (
                        <OwnReply
                            // key={index}
                            replyId={replyId}
                            onContent={replyText}
                            onTime={createdAt}
                            onCount={score}
                            onTar={postedBy}
                            postedBy={postedBy}
                            createdAt={createdAt}
                            ava={ava}
                            onDel={deleteReply}
                            // replies={replies}
                            comId={comId}
                            avatar={avatar}
                            recipeId={recipeId}
                            onCommentDeleted={onCommentDeleted}
                            onReplyDelete={onReplyDelete}

                        />
                    ) : (
                        <Card key={rep.replyId}>
                            <Box sx={{ p: "15px" }}>
                                <Stack spacing={2} direction="row">
                                    <Box>
                                        {/* <ScoreChanger onScore={score} /> */}
                                    </Box>
                                    <Box sx={{ width: "100%" }}>
                                        <Stack
                                            spacing={2}
                                            direction="row"
                                            justifyContent="space-between"
                                            alignItems="center"
                                        >
                                            <Stack spacing={2} direction="row" alignItems="center">
                                                <Avatar src={ava}></Avatar>
                                                <Typography
                                                    fontWeight="bold"
                                                    sx={{ color: "neutral.darkBlue" }}
                                                >
                                                    {userName}
                                                </Typography>
                                                <Typography sx={{ color: "neutral.grayishBlue" }}>
                                                    {createdAt && createdAt.toDate().toLocaleString()}
                                                </Typography>
                                            </Stack>
                                            <Button
                                                variant="text"
                                                sx={{
                                                    fontWeight: 500,
                                                    textTransform: "capitalize",
                                                    color: "custom.moderateBlue",
                                                }}
                                                startIcon={<Image src={replyArrow} alt="reply sign" />}
                                            >
                                                Reply
                                            </Button>
                                        </Stack>
                                        <Typography
                                            component="div"
                                            sx={{ color: "neutral.grayishBlue", p: "20px 0" }}
                                        >
                                            <Typography
                                                sx={{
                                                    color: "custom.moderateBlue",
                                                    width: "fit-content",
                                                    display: "inline-block",
                                                    fontWeight: 500,
                                                }}
                                            >
                                                {`@${postedBy}`}
                                            </Typography>{" "}
                                            {replyText}
                                        </Typography>
                                    </Box>
                                </Stack>
                            </Box>
                        </Card>
                    );
                })
            }
            {onClicked && <AddReply

                onPass={onPass}
                ava={ava}
                displayName={displayName}
            />}
        </Stack>
    );
};

export default RepliesSection;
```

**OwnReply.js**

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from "react";
import { Delete, Edit } from "@mui/icons-material";
import {
    Box,
    Card,
    Stack,
    Typography,
    Avatar,
    Button,
    TextField,
} from "@mui/material";
import YouTag from "./YouTag";
// import CommentContext from "../commentContext";
// import ScoreChanger from "./ScoreChanger";
import ConfirmDelete from "./ConfirmDelete";
import { getFirestore, doc, arrayRemove, getDoc, updateDoc } from "firebase/firestore";
const OwnReply = ({ onCommentDeleted, onDel, replies, postedBy, onContent, setReplyData, onCount, onTar, comId, ava, index, reply, replyId, recipeId, createdAt, avatar, replyText, onReplyDelete }) => {
    // console.log(reply)
    const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false);
    const [editingRep, setEditingRep] = useState(false);
    const [repText, setRepText] = useState(onContent);
    const [openModal, setOpenModal] = useState(false);
    const db = getFirestore()
    const handleOpen = () => {
        setOpenModal(true);
    };

    const handleClose = () => {
        setOpenModal(false);
    };



    return (
        <>
            <ConfirmDelete
                onOpen={openModal}
                onClose={handleClose}
                comId={comId}
                index={index}
                reply={reply}
                isReply={true}
                replies={replies}
                replyId={replyId}
                recipeId={recipeId}
                avatar={avatar}
                createdAt={createdAt}
                postedBy={postedBy}
                replyText={replyText}
                onDel={onDel}
            // onConfirm={() => handleDelete(index)}
            />
            <Card>
                <Box sx={{ p: "15px" }}>
                    <Stack spacing={2} direction="row">
                        <Box>
                            {/* <ScoreChanger onScore={onCount} /> */}
                        </Box>
                        <Box sx={{ width: "100%" }}>
                            <Stack
                                spacing={2}
                                direction="row"
                                justifyContent="space-between"
                                alignItems="center"
                            >
                                <Stack spacing={2} direction="row" alignItems="center">
                                    <Avatar src={ava}></Avatar>
                                    <Typography
                                        fontWeight="bold"
                                        sx={{ color: "neutral.darkBlue" }}
                                    >
                                        {postedBy}
                                    </Typography>
                                    <YouTag />
                                    <Typography sx={{ color: "neutral.grayishBlue" }}>
                                        Just now
                                    </Typography>
                                </Stack>
                                <Stack direction="row" spacing={1}>
                                    <Button
                                        startIcon={<Delete />}
                                        sx={{
                                            color: "custom.softRed",
                                            fontWeight: 500,
                                            textTransform: "capitalize",
                                        }}
                                        onClick={() => {
                                            handleOpen();
                                        }}
                                    >
                                        Delete
                                    </Button>
                                    <Button
                                        variant="text"
                                        disabled={clicked}
                                        sx={{
                                            fontWeight: 500,
                                            textTransform: "capitalize",
                                            color: "custom.moderateBlue",
                                        }}
                                        startIcon={<Edit />}
                                        onClick={() => {
                                            setClicked(!clicked);
                                            setEditingRep(!editingRep);
                                        }}
                                    >
                                        Edit
                                    </Button>
                                </Stack>
                            </Stack>
                            {editingRep ? (
                                <>
                                    <TextField
                                        sx={{ p: "20px 0" }}
                                        multiline
                                        fullWidth
                                        minRows={4}
                                        id="outlined-multilined"
                                        placeholder="Don't leave this blank!"
                                        value={repText}
                                        onChange={(e) => {
                                            setRepText(e.target.value);
                                        }}
                                    />
                                    <Button
                                        sx={{
                                            bgcolor: "custom.moderateBlue",
                                            color: "neutral.white",
                                            p: "8px 25px",
                                            float: "right",
                                            "&:hover": {
                                                bgcolor: "custom.lightGrayishBlue",
                                            },
                                        }}
                                        onClick={() => {
                                            !repText.trim()
                                                ? alert("Read the placeholder.")
                                                : setEditingRep(!editingRep);
                                            setClicked(!clicked);
                                            console.log("check if it works");
                                        }}
                                    >
                                        Update
                                    </Button>
                                </>
                            ) : (
                                <Typography
                                    component="div"
                                    sx={{ color: "neutral.grayishBlue", p: "20px 0" }}
                                >
                                    <Typography
                                        sx={{
                                            color: "custom.moderateBlue",
                                            width: "fit-content",
                                            display: "inline-block",
                                            fontWeight: 500,
                                        }}
                                    >
                                        {`@${onTar}`}
                                    </Typography>{" "}
                                    {repText}
                                </Typography>
                            )}
                        </Box>
                    </Stack>
                </Box>
            </Card>
        </>
    );
};

export default OwnReply;
```

**ConfirmDelete.js**

```
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  Button,
  Stack,
  Typography,
  Dialog,
  DialogTitle,
  DialogContent,
} from "@mui/material";
import { AuthContext } from "../../../context/AuthContext";
import { getFirestore, doc, deleteDoc, getDoc, updateDoc, arrayRemove, update, FieldValue } from "firebase/firestore";



const ConfirmDelete = ({ setReplyId, replyId, onDel, onOpen, onClose, comId, onCommentDeleted, onReplyDelete, index, isReply, replies, id, recipeId, postedBy, avatar, createdAt }) => {
  const [commentData, setCommentData] = useState([]);
  const { currentUser } = useContext(AuthContext);

  const db = getFirestore()
  const docRef = doc(db, 'comments/' + `${comId}`)

  const deleteHandler = async () => {
    try {
      await deleteDoc(docRef);
      onCommentDeleted(id); // call the onCommentDeleted callback function
      onClose();
    } catch (error) {

    }
  };



  return (
    <Dialog open={onOpen} onClose={onClose}>
      <DialogContent sx={{ maxWidth: "430px" }}>
        <DialogTitle sx={{ p: "0", marginBottom: "20px" }}>
          Delete comment
        </DialogTitle>
        <Typography
          component="p"
          sx={{ marginBottom: "20px", color: "neutral.grayishBlue" }}
        >
          Are you sure you want to delete this comment? This will remove the
          comment and it can't be undone.
        </Typography>
        <Stack direction="row" display="flex" justifyContent="space-between">
          <Button
            variant="contained"
            disableElevation
            sx={{
              bgcolor: "neutral.grayishBlue",
              "&:hover": { bgcolor: "neutral.grayishBlue" },
            }}
            onClick={onClose}
          >
            No, cancel
          </Button>
          <Button
            variant="contained"
            disableElevation
            sx={{
              bgcolor: "custom.softRed",
              "&:hover": { bgcolor: "custom.softRed" },
            }}
            onClick={() => {
              onDel ? onDel(replyId) : deleteHandler(id);
            }}

          >
            Yes, delete
          </Button>
        </Stack>
      </DialogContent>
    </Dialog>
  );
};

export default ConfirmDelete;
```

Comment: what have you tried to debug the problem? Is deleteReply is called? Are repliess changes after updateDoc finished?

Comment: That is *a lot* of code for us to parse through. Are you having difficulty with a specific section of code? If so, can you isolate the section of code and update the question by describing the issue and your troubleshooting? Meanwhile, please take a moment and review [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

I am not a Firebase user, so I don't know the fine details of how those parts of the code interact with React. I will do my best :)

Analysis:

It seems your `repliess` state in `RepliesSection` creates a copy of the actual replies in the comment, which would mean `RepliesSection` is an uncontrolled component. It starts with a state and keeps its own state. This means there is a duplication of state - each `RepliesSection` has its own list of replies, and `Comments` has its comments each with a list of replies. This isn't necessarily a problem in and of itself, but it could make some code hard to reason about because there are two copies of the data that could get out of sync.

I see you do `updateDoc` and `setReplies` in the `deleteReply` function. Theoretically, this should update the Firebase data and update `repliess` in your `RepliesSection`. Have you confirmed that your `onSnapshot` in `Comments` runs and properly runs `setComments` with the updated reply data after you run `updateDoc` in `deleteReply`? (I'm assuming this is the intended functionality as I do not know Firebase.)

I expect if `setComments` does properly run with the removed reply, it should trigger a deletion and a re-creation of `RepliesSection` with the new set of replies with one removed. Does this happen? If so, I expect this to work (with a console error - see next paragraph). Would be good to know if this is happening for further investigation.

However, if `setComments` doesn't run with the new data and cause `RepliesSection` to be recreated with new data, I wonder if there is another issue going on: your `deleteReply` function is asynchronous and runs `setReplies` after an `await`. This means that, if the `RepliesSection` element is destroyed before `setReplies` is run, `setReplies` will still run but on a deleted React element. Do you see any errors in your console about updating state after an element is destroyed? I wonder if somehow `SingleComment` is deleting and recreating `RepliesSection` with the old reply data because `deleteReply` doesn't actually change `SingleComment`'s replies. I haven't noticed anything that would cause this to happen; just guessing at what I have seen commonly in other situations.

---

Suggestion:

I recommend (after doing the debugging I recommended above to see if you can figure out the problem. Probably good for understanding to figure out the problem before restructuring) changing `RepliesSection` to be a controlled component. This means `RepliesSection` would display `onReplies` directly instead of creating its own state `repliess` based on `onReplies`. You could create a `deleteReply` function in `Comments` that does the work of running `updateDoc` and `setComments` with new reply data inside (note that you'll have to re-assign the `comments` array, not just the replies of a specific comment, to a new reference to make React rerender since `Comments` is listening for changes to `comments`, not the data inside. You can simply destructure the array in to a new array like `setComments([...comments])` to update its reference. However, if you ever memoize `SingleComment`, you'll also want to update each comment's reference as well. `immer` is a nice library for easy updates to immutable data structures. However, I honestly expect the `setComments` in `onSnapshot` should be doing this for you if it is actually running). If you pass `deleteReply` down to `RepliesSection`, that would mean `RepliesSection` is getting its data and running functions that update the data that come from the same place, keeping data and its modifying functions in the same place (in `Comments`). Hopefully that would help with understanding how the data is changing and how it translates into React rerenders.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, this absolutely set me off on the right direction. I elevated the state up to comments and made the RepliesSection a controlled component as you suggested. What i found though is that state was re-rendering after i deleted the correct reply, it was choosing the wrong array element to remove because i misconfigured my key that rendered the replies, i had "temporarily" commented it out but also used an invalid identifier anyway. Once i used my replyId as a key it all started working as desired.